# How to grab card holder information using Square iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, square, square-connect

I have used Square Register SDK into my iOS application. While everything is working fine, I need to keep the record of non-sensitive information of the card-holders who would make transactions using my Square Contactless hardware and Square iOS Register SDK.

But I couldn't find anything related to Card or Cardholder in the Register SDK. What is the simplest way to grab the card holder name for a specific transaction made using Register SDK?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you looking for? Most of that information isn't available to you for compliance reasons. The easiest way is to use the REST APIs to retrieve the transaction See the official Documentation: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#endpoint-retrievetransaction

Comment: I just want to get non-sensitive credit card information (cardholder name) for a transaction that is done using Square Register SDK. 
I had a look at transactions API of Square Connect V2, but it doesn't contain the Card information.

Comment: Square considers cardholder name to be sensitive, and does not allow you to get the name that the card is registered to. You can ask for users  to input their name from within your app. Why do you need a record of cardholder names? Would a transaction id do instead?

Comment: It's basically a store checkin system, whosoever checks in into the store would be charged a dollar per day. Now we want to keep track of the people who visit our store. How can we get the name or email of the people who would be making transactions using Square POS (Square Register iOS SDK). ? Is it possible?

Comment: In your iOS or Android app just ask them for their name or email in the check out flow. Would that work?

Comment: No, it's an automated app and we don't want to enter anything manually :(

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to have a totally 'tap & go' experience. The end user will need put some input as to who they are.

Comment: Thank you for your response. One thing more I would like to ask is, if we have a customers list linked to our Square account. By using Square Connect V2, there is a customers List API which can be hit to grab customers list. In the response there is a field something like `"updated_at": "2016-03-23T20:21:55Z"`, is the time stamp of this field updated whenever any customer performs a transaction or it is only associated with the customer-specific information like name, email etc.

Comment: It is the time when the customer was last updated, not the last transaction time. (the latter in your list)